# Can you use self.assertRaises as an async context manager?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'd like to test that a python 3 coro fails with a particular exception, but this functionality doesn't seem to be implemented.

```
async with self.assertRaises(TestExceptionType):
    await my_func()
```

as the unit test fails like this:

```
...
File "/Users/...../tests.py", line 144, in go
    async with self.assertRaises(TestExceptionType):
AttributeError: __aexit__
```

So my question is: should this work? And if not, what's the best way to assert a failing async function?

Comment: Why do you need an async context manager here? `with self.assertRaises(TestExceptionType):` should be sufficient here since `assertRaises` does nothing asynchronously.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use classic old good `with` around `await` call:

```
with self.assertRaises(TestExceptionType):
    await my_func()
```

It works.